# Use $gte and &lte mongo operator if date is in string format in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have dob field like `{dob:"02-23-2000"}` in database. Now I want to perform `$gte` and `&lte` on dob field that is in string format like below:

```
db.panelists.count({"dob":{ '$gte': '08-02-1998', '$lte': '08-02-2003' }});
```

I am getting count value as zero always.

Could anyone please help me out to resolve this query in same dob format.

Comment: mongodb version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am using 3.6 db verion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.6**

You can use [**`$dateFromString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) aggregation to convert your `dob` from 
string to date and then easily [**`$count`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) the documents applying [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on it.

**1)** **Using aggregation with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)**

```
db.panelists.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }
    } 
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "date": {
      "$gte": moment('08-02-1998').toDate(),
      "$lte": moment('08-02-2003').toDate()
    }
  }},
  { "$count": "count" }
])
```

**2)** **Using simple find query with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)**

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$gte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},
          ISODate("2000-02-22T00:00:00Z")
        ]
      },
      {
        "$lte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},
          ISODate("2000-02-24T00:00:00Z")
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

**3)** **Using aggregation with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$gte": [
            { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},
            ISODate("2000-02-22T00:00:00Z")
          ]
        },
        {
          "$lte": [
            { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},
            ISODate("2000-02-24T00:00:00Z")
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Or if the strings were in the proper ISO8601, string comparisons would have worked just as well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes , but as OP stored dob in string format that's why conversation is needed

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am getting error "ReferenceError: moment is not defined" and when I google this error I found moment is node js function and it can not be run on mongo shell.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: Yes, I mean strings in ISO8601. `dob: "1998-02-08"`. With this format, you can compare strings directly.

Comment: @NileshKumar use directly `ISODate("2018-07-15T07:05:03.880Z")` ... moment is for nodejs... moment will convert your string('08-02-1998') date to `ISODate()` and then will easily
match with dob `ISODate()` in nodejs

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet dob value is in string format it is not in ISO format. If I will use ISODate with string then it will give error "Invalid ISO date"

Comment: @NileshKumar does the above query work for you... Because it is working for me in mongoshell... try it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/sF77cfQIwg9

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks for the answer. +1 and accepted the answer.

Comment: Just to know one thing what if I am on 3.0 mongo version then how it will happen

Comment: @NileshKumar there is no way to do this with **lower mongodb versions** and that's why these types of aggregation has been introduced in mongodb...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ***With this format, you can compare strings directly.*** Yes are right if the date in the database is also in string format.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet. Naturally. Also, that's what he has. Hence my comment.