# Get Data Between String Date MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem how to get data between start date because it's just string and my document schema like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ab92bdd6fbcd28fb0c68ff6"),
"username" : "jumbreng",
"startdate" : "26-03-2018",
"enddate" : "11-08-2018",
"status" : 1
```

i have been try create aggregation like this

```
    db.presensi.aggregate( [ {
   $project: {   
      "username": "$username",
      "startdate": {
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$startdate',
         }
      },
      "enddate" :{
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$enddate',
         }
   }
   }
} ] )
```

but i don't know hot to make this have range like find($lte and $gte)
should i update this aggregation to my collection?and then i can crate statement find($lte and $gte)? how to make aggregation to my collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use $gte and &lte mongo operator if date is in string format in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647245/how-to-use-gte-and-lte-mongo-operator-if-date-is-in-string-format-in-mongodb)

Comment: You can try this probably the best way to do  [How to use $gte and &lte mongo operator if date is in string format in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647245/how-to-use-gte-and-lte-mongo-operator-if-date-is-in-string-format-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) aggregation operator can help you.

try it:

```
db.user.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $project: {
            _id: true,
            startdate: true,
            enddate: true,
            status: true,
            username: "$username",
            isBetween: {
                $and: [{
                    $lt: [{
                        $dateFromString: {
                            dateString: '$startdate',
                        }
                    }, {
                        $dateFromString: {
                            dateString: '27-03-2018',
                        }
                    }]
                }, {
                    $gt: [{
                        $dateFromString: {
                            dateString: '$startdate',
                        }
                    }, {
                        $dateFromString: {
                            dateString: '25-03-2018',
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $match: {
            "isBetween": true
        }
    },
], {
    cursor: {
        batchSize: 50
    }
});
```

Comment: but aggregation doesnt support $gte.

Comment: can you give me some example from my collection like that?

Comment: sorry sir i have been edited and try your solution.but how to create this aggregation to my collection?