# How to retrieve data based on the date range of string date field in a nested document of a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-collection

**Requirement in High level:**

I have a peculiar requirement where I want to return the specific project in which specific type of property got sold between some dates.

**Detailed Requirement**

I have projects collection in which we store all projects related data. That collection contains different sections in which one of the section deal with sale date information of all types of properties in that project.

So now I want to pull the projects whose "Villa" types are sold between "2018-10-01" (YYYY-mm-dd) and "2019-09-30" (YYYY-mm-dd).

**My Collection Structure with Sample Data**

```
db.getCollection('projects').find({})

{
    "_id" : "11a2c36923fe24da490f81626742234f",
    "project" : "highlands_1.0",
    "project_sale_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "dates" : "2019-06-13"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "dates" : "2019-07-11"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "dates" : "2019-07-11",
            "comments" : "No issues"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Open Plot"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "dates" : "2019-10-15"
        }
    ],
    "repay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "installment2" : "2019-11-01",
            "installment3" : "2019-10-25",
            "installment4" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "installment1" : "2019-12-20",
            "installment2" : "2019-12-06",
            "installment3" : "2019-11-29",
            "installment4" : "2019-11-15"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment3" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment4" : "2020-02-26"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-27",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-20"
        }
    ],
    "lease_pay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-10-21",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-11-01"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-01-03",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-12-20"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-03-24",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "comments" : "3 days before HM synth start"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "11a2c36923fe24da490f81626742234f",
    "project" : "green_fields_1.0",
    "project_sale_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "dates" : "2019-06-13"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "dates" : "2019-07-11"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "dates" : "2020-07-11"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Open Plot"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "dates" : "2019-10-15"
        }
    ],
    "repay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "installment2" : "2019-11-01",
            "installment3" : "2019-10-25",
            "installment4" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "installment1" : "2019-12-20",
            "installment2" : "2019-12-06",
            "installment3" : "2019-11-29",
            "installment4" : "2019-11-15"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment3" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment4" : "2020-02-26"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-27",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-20"
        }
    ],
    "lease_pay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-10-21",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-11-01"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-01-03",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-12-20"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-03-24",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "comments" : "3 days before HM synth start"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "11a2c36923fe24da490f81626742234f",
    "project" : "green_fields_2.0",
    "project_sale_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "dates" : "2019-06-13"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "dates" : "2019-07-11"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Open Plot"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "dates" : "2019-10-15"
        }
    ],
    "repay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "installment2" : "2019-11-01",
            "installment3" : "2019-10-25",
            "installment4" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "installment1" : "2019-12-20",
            "installment2" : "2019-12-06",
            "installment3" : "2019-11-29",
            "installment4" : "2019-11-15"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment3" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment4" : "2020-02-26"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-27",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-20"
        }
    ],
    "lease_pay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-10-21",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-11-01"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-01-03",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-12-20"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-03-24",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "comments" : "3 days before HM synth start"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "11a2c36923fe24da490f81626742234f",
    "project" : "high_value_1.0",
    "project_sale_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "dates" : "2019-06-13"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "dates" : "2019-07-11"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "dates" : "2019-09-11"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Open Plot"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "dates" : "2019-10-15"
        }
    ],
    "repay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "installment2" : "2019-11-01",
            "installment3" : "2019-10-25",
            "installment4" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "installment1" : "2019-12-20",
            "installment2" : "2019-12-06",
            "installment3" : "2019-11-29",
            "installment4" : "2019-11-15"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment3" : "2020-03-10",
            "installment4" : "2020-02-26"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "installment1" : "2020-03-27",
            "installment2" : "2020-03-20"
        }
    ],
    "lease_pay_schedule" : [ 
        {
            "project_type" : "Condo",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-10-21",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-10-14"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Apartment",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2019-11-15",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-11-01"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Villa",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-01-03",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2019-12-20"
        }, 
        {
            "project_type" : "Fenced Plot",
            "req_date_installment1" : "2020-03-24",
            "req_date_installment2" : "2020-03-10",
            "comments" : "3 days before HM synth start"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The final output I'm interested in when I run the query is**

```
**Result:**

{
    "project" : "highlands_1.0"
},
{
    "project" : "high_value_1.0"
}

or

["highlands_1.0", "high_value_1.0"]
```

**Note:** I don't want the Projects **"green_fields_1.0","green_fields_2.0"**, since either the sale of **Villa** type of property not falls between the date range or date is not present.

I came across the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805100/get-data-between-string-date-mongodb). which handles something similar to my question but the data structure of my collection made it not possible for me to aggregate the data.

**My Mongo Version:** 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.   The trick is to use `$filter` then `$match` on the size of the filtered array.   The output is a bit more than you asked for but you can easily add another project to remove the `X` arrray.

```
var sdate = ISODate("2018-10-01");
var edate = ISODate("2019-09-30");

c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {
    project: true,  // carry the project field into the output...
    X: {$filter: {
            input: "$project_sale_schedule",
            as: "zz",
            cond: {$and:[
                {$eq: ['$$zz.project_type',"Villa"]}
                ,{$gte: [{$dateFromString: { dateString: "$$zz.dates", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}},sdate]}
                ,{$lt: [{$dateFromString: { dateString: "$$zz.dates", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}},edate]}
            ]
                  }
        }}
    }}
    ,{$match: {$expr: {$gt: [ {$size:"$X"}, 0 ] }}}
]);
```

There is a fancier version that uses `$let` which allows us to convert the string to a date just once.   Note:  Probably a good idea if you could use actual datetime types in your docs instead of strings.

```
        X: {$filter: {
            input: "$project_sale_schedule",
            as: "zz",
            cond: {$let: {
                vars: {dd: {$dateFromString: { dateString: "$$zz.dates", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}}},
                in: {$and:[
                    {$eq: ['$$zz.project_type',"Villa"]}
                    ,{$gte: ["$$dd",sdate]}
                    ,{$lt: ["$$dd",edate]}
                ]}
            }}

        }}
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you @Buzz Moschetti. It worked like a charm. And one note here. Since I'm using the Mongo Version 3.6.2. I have to strip of "format" from the "$dateFromString" options. Since "format" was not part of the Mongo 3.6 "$dateFromString" release. And the additional projection to remove the X is also a good point. You saved a lot of my time. And  another note. I do follow date field for dates. Since this is a old DB and a lot of data was initially pumped with string dates. I can't do much about it. That's about it. Thanks once again.